# make elements below (not direct) an image not be affected by floating the image

Tags: css

I have the following code, which includes an image and text and some other info after it's parent. My concern is that the element following its parent is affected by floating the image, is there a way I can make that element appear normally.

```css
.floated {float:left;}
```

```html
<div = "parent">
  <p>This text is above the picture.</p>
<img class = "floated" src = "http://www.userlogos.org/files/logos/pek/stackoverflow2.png"/>
  <p>This text should wrap around the floated image</p>
  </div>
<div = "another_element">
  <p class = "not_floated">This text shouldn't be affected by the floated image, but for some reason it is what should be done to it.</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: The fastest solution is add add { overflow: hidden } to parent element

Comment: @wawka, It's right, but only if you're sure that the parent element won't have overflown data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add class `.fix` to the parent or the last `p` and set the `.fix:after` css as below: [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/8kct0k47/1/) <sup>( 1 )</sup>

```css
.floated {
  float: left;
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
.fix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" class="fix">
  <p>This text is above the picture.</p>
  <img class="floated" src="http://www.userlogos.org/files/logos/pek/stackoverflow2.png" />
  <p>This text should wrap around the floated image</p>
</div>
<div id="another_element">
  <p class="not_floated">This text shouldn't be affected by the floated image, but for some reason it is what should be done to it.</p>
</div>
```

---

<sup>( 1 )</sup> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/